# vertical align <span> element

Tags: html, css

html

```
<div class="main">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <span class="details">Jan 21, 2014</span>
</div>
```

css

```
.main{
    background-color: #666666;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
h1{
    background-color: #383838;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.main span{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8H9dR/)

This seems to be really a simple problem, but I'm not able to fix it or I'm being too lazy. Just would like to `vertical-align: middle` and align it to the right of the div, if I use `float: right` the element attaches to the bottom of the border above. Don't want to use `line-height` as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a solution that doesn't include <s>`line-height`</s>, and `float`, also you want to *align* the `span` to the *right* ....

Then use `display: table;` for the parent element having nested child elements set to `display: table-cell;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VC2z4/)

```
.main{
    background-color: #666666;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
h1{
    background-color: #383838;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20%;
}
.main span{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to add `vertical-align: middle;` to your `h1`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesking/8H9dR/1/)

Comment: I don't think this would suffice ***and align it to the right of the div*** else I would've answered the same

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that requirement. Mr. Alien's answer is the way you want to go then